# Como cambiar de INSERT a UPDATE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Recién comienzo con PL/SQL y necesito de sus ayudas, estoy realizando un procedimiento en el cual tengo un `INSERT` en el cual guarda ciertos valores en una tabla, lo que necesito al final de cuentas, es que no se me agregue un nuevo registro si no que se me actualiza el registro actual.

El siguiente es el procedimiento que llevo realizando

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRUEBAINSERT

TEXT_COMP VARCHAR2(32767);
P_PIDEM NUMBER;
V_FILENAME  VARCHAR2(30);
TEXT_COMP VARCHAR2(32767);

BEGIN 

--Se inserta los datos en la tabla
        INSERT INTO SPRCMNT (SPRCMNT_PIDM, SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE, SPRCMNT_TEXT, SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR, SPRCMNT_ACTIVITY_DATE)
                         VALUES(P_PIDM, '15', V_FILENAME, TEXT_COMP, SYSDATE);
COMMIT;

END;
```

Comment: Cambia el insert por un [Update](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php) y en la where escribes la clausula que quieres que cumpla para actualizar esa/s linea/s. Si usas una condición que devuelva una fila solo se actualizara esa fila, pero si devuelve mas se cambiaran todas (por lo que si solo quieres actualizar una en concreto usa la PK o un campo unico).

Comment: Quiero que en especifico se actualice lo que se encuentra en el campo 
 `SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR`

Comment: Será algo así, `UPDATE SPRCMNT  SET SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR = TEXT_COMP WHERE ID = SU_ID;`, la where es la condición que tu quieras, como una query normal. Si devuelve varias filas se actualizaran todas.

Comment: Puedes comentarlo como respuesta por favor para darle validez a la respuesta y continuar con el procedimiento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo tienes que cambiar el `insert` por un [`update`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/update.php):

Estructura:

> ```
> UPDATE table
> SET column1 = expression1,
>     column2 = (SELECT expression2
>                FROM table2
>                WHERE conditions),
>     ...
>     column_n = expression_n
> [WHERE conditions];
> ```

Ejemplo:

```
UPDATE SPRCMNT 
SET SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR = TEXT_COMP 
WHERE ID = SU_ID;
```

Los campos del `set` se encadenan con comas y no tienen que seguir un orden:

```
UPDATE SPRCMNT 
SET SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR = TEXT_COMP,
SPRCMNT_CMTT_CODE = '15'
WHERE ID = SU_ID;
```

El `where` es la condición que quieres que cumpla tu `query`, si devuelve una fila solo se actualizara esa fila, mientras que si devuelve mas todas serán actualizadas. Si quieres que sea una condición para una fila especifica usa la `primary_key` o un campo `unique` en el `where`.

**La condición `where` es OPCIONAL, si no se especifica se actualizaran todos los campos de la tabla especificada.**

Comment: Adicional al campo `SPRCMNT_TEXT_NAR` también quiero que se actualice el `SPRCMNT_ACTIVITY_DATE`, este almacenara una fecha y es importante saber cuando se actualizo

Comment: @SebastianSalazar Como he puesto en la respuesta, puedes encadenar varios campos que quieres que se actualicen en el `set` con _comas_. Todos los campos que quieras de la tabla los puedes actualizar.